# How to Import Amazon S3 bucket without API Key?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

From what I've researched, it seems that S3 buckets are typically downloaded from the same AWS account that the API Key originates from.

I have been given access to a new AWS account, and this account contains an S3 bucket that I need to download on a daily basis. The issue is that I have my API key associated with another AWS account. Is there any way to import the new S3 bucket into my existing AWS account, or would it be simpler to try and create a new API key on the AWS account which already has the S3 bucket I need?

I am using python and boto3. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know the exact answer with what you are doing with python... but you can't just import their s3 bucket into your aws account. You can't transfer it either. What you could do is sync both, you will need to issue a key from the account that owns that other bucket, so you can access it and consume it. Then with the CLI sync both.  `aws s3 sync s3://mybucket s3://mybucket2` Check this out: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html

Comment: One option: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html.

Answer (score 0):

The owner of the Amazon S3 bucket can add a Bucket Policy that grants access either publicly or to specific AWS users, including users from another AWS account. This way, you can use credentials from Account A to access a bucket in Account B.

For example, this Bucket Policy grants access to a user in a different account:

```
{
  "Id": "S3Access",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "DownloadFiles",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/fred"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "ListFiles",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/fred"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The ARN can be obtained by looking at the IAM User within the IAM management console.

Rather than downloading the whole bucket each time, I would recommend using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), which has a convenient `aws s3 sync` command. This can synchronize files to/from Amazon S3 and will only copy files that have been added or modified since the last sync. You could run it on a regular basis (eg each hour) to have a local copy of the bucket, similar in concept to DropBox.